# merge C# console application into an MVC 4 app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wsdl, soap-client

I am writing to get suggestions and opinions.

I have a console application that is using a SOAP Web Service.

I have finished implementing all the logic I need in a console app and now I need to build a web page for it.

I am thinking of using MVC instead of C# Web Application as suggested by peers.

I hope that I can get some pointers of how to start working with this.

How could I merge the existing project into the MVC project? and would all of my back end logic sit in the model part?? I am getting confused about the MVC concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your backend logic would sit in a Controller Action Method, where you would eventually create a strongly typed Model or dynamically into the ViewBag dynamic type. Your View (aspx or cshtml) would consume that information and bind it to the page.

Please see http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials for more information/tutorials.